# Pass objects or values to functions

Tags: c#

*This question has been edited to ask about a specific example as the original question was deemed unanswerable.*

Given an application that needs to display information about various objects (including similar and inherited objects) would it be better to pass in base class objects to the display function and allow it to query the object to determine what data to display; or should you just pass in each of the fields by value. The advantage of passing by value being do not need a direct dependency on the objects they representing, thus keeping the display (UI) isolated from the business rule objects.

Comment: "It depends" and is very *not* language-agnostic: general functions are nice, but do not necessarily override other contracts.

Comment: This is not constructive (meaning not answerable). It's like "What's better - a car or a truck?" - the right answer depends on whether or not you need to haul people in comfort or bales of hay. "What's better? A dog or a cat?" depends on whether you're trying to get rid of mice or you want to have a pet to play fetch and guard your house. Voting to close. Sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've changed the question to reflect a specific example I've struggled with in the past. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should pass the minimum amount of information that a method needs to do its job. For example, if a method is computing a person's age given their birth date, you don't need to pass in the entire Person object, you just need the person's birth date and the current date.

By following the above approach, you keep your methods [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29), which makes them much more maintainable.

In your case, you have to balance whether you need to access a lot of fields of the base classes in these methods, or if you are just need to access a few. If it's a lot of fields, then it may make more sense to just pass the entire object. It's sort of a balancing act between having good coupling (see first part of this answer), but at the same time, avoiding passing tons of parameters to a method.